# Using Datastax Java Driver to return JSON

Tags: java, json, scala, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to use the datastax java driver and retrieve and return JSON.

```
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute("SELECT JSON * FROM event");

Row row = resultSet.one();
String json1 = row.getString(0);
String json2 = row.getString("[json]");

    System.out.println(resultSet.toString());
returns  ResultSet[ exhausted: false, Columns[[json](varchar)]]
```

At this point of time, I'm aware of the code to retrieve one row. I wish to return all rows as a json string

Comment: You don't want to retrieve **all** rows as JSON string. Because if there are 1 million rows, you'll have a HUGE string ...

Comment: @doanduyhai Yes I want and i dont have 1 million rows .... plus it's a SQL query...

Comment: In this case, do a for loop on all rows and concatenate the JSON strings together

Comment: @doandduyhai, not sure how to do it on java with this, http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At this point of time, I'm aware of the code to retrieve one row. I wish to return all rows as a json string.

**Java 8 StringJoiner**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html

```
StringJoiner jsonString = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
for(Row row: resultSet.all()) {
   String json = row.getString(0);
   jsonString.add(json);
}

return jsonString.toString();
```

Comment: I used StringBuilder, StringJoiner is definitely a better option. Thanks!